# Best way to draw/render grid iOS - Game of Life

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, c

I am taking a stab at John Conway's game of life [[wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) & [[demo]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcuBvj0pw-E). I have developed a [small program in C](https://github.com/nbdevries/game_of_life_c) to calculate the next state - using a 1D array (but with 2D array logic).

I am hoping to make a small iOS app out of this (to Objective-C!), and am wondering the best and fastest way to render a grid like seen in the video. Note, it would have to render every fraction of a second and would use an array of `1`'s and `0`'s to determine a "block's" respective colour.

**Edit:** I'm probably looking at around 10 frames/sec, but a very large grid. It'd be rendering out hundreds of thousands of squares. Of course, if this isn't physically possible with iPhone/iPad technology then I'll reduce the grid size. It is variable without issue, just looks more 'epic' on a grand scale.

Any suggestions will help out, never touched anything of this manner before.

Comment: For iPad, at 1 point/cell, you're limited to about 780k points. (I would not use retina pixels, since they are too small to visualize. If you want less cells than that, the next dividing point would be 2point x  2-point cells, which would give you about 196k cells. You're probably going to have to some performance benchmarking to figure out how fast you can draw pixels.

Comment: Did you ever move your code over to Metal or OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

The best way depends on your criteria. Fastest would probably be to use OpenGL. You might even be able to write a shader to do the entire simulation. However, OpenGL is hard. **Really** hard.

I suspect that using Core Graphics and implementing code in a view's drawRect method that renders the array of cells onto the screen would be fast enough. It depends on how many cells you have and how many frames/second you want to draw.